# How to make each angular component have a different array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, for-loop

I have angular component which is displaying crypto currency prices from API. In the same service, I have an array of hard coded star rating values for each component. When I'm looping through each value from API, I also make an inside for loop to iterate through hard coded array of object literals and attach unique array value for rating for each crypto component. Older version (commented out) worked, but displayed same rating info for all crypto components. Now I commented it out and put more values in array to make it more simple. Here is the code. I don't get any errors, only undefined in console and rating component stops showing up in crypto component.

```
getProducts() {
        return this.http.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT,TRX&tsyms=USD')
  .map(result => {
    Object.keys(result).forEach(value => {

      // add logic to have each crypto a different rating
      var ratings = [{rating: 4, numOfReviews: 2}, {rating:5, numOfReviews: 3}, {rating:6, numOfReviews:1}];
      for(var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
        result[value]['ratingInfo'] = ratings[i].rating;
        result[value]['ratingInfo'] = ratings[i].numOfReviews;
      }

    /*  result[value]['ratingInfo'] = {
        imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=1",
        productName: "Product 1",
        releasedDate: "May 31, 2016",
        description: "Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.",
        rating: 4,
        numOfReviews: 2
      }*/
    });
    return result;
  });
}
```

Crypto.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { RatingComponent } from './rating.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'crypto',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `<h2 class="header">Crypto Price Compare</h2>
    <div *ngIf="cryptos">
    <div id="crypto-container" *ngFor="let crypto of objectKeys(cryptos)">
      <span class="left">{{ crypto }}</span>
      <span class="right">{{ cryptos[crypto].USD | currency:'USD':true }}</span>
      <br />
      <rating
      [rating-value]="cryptos[crypto].ratingInfo.rating"
      [numOfReviews]="cryptos[crypto].ratingInfo.numOfReviews">
  </rating>
    </div>
  </div>`
})
export class CryptoComponent {
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
cryptos: any;
ratings: any;

constructor(private _data: ProductService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this._data.getProducts()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.cryptos = res;
      console.log(res);
    });

  //this.ratings = this._data.getRatings();
    console.log(this.ratings);


}

    onClick($event){
      console.log("Clicked",$event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the implementation of your ProductService like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  ...
  getProducts() {

    const ratings = [
      { rating: 4, numOfReviews: 2 }, 
      { rating: 5, numOfReviews: 3 }, 
      { rating: 6, numOfReviews: 1 },
      { rating: 7, numOfReviews: 4 }
    ];

    return this.http.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT,TRX&tsyms=USD')
      .pipe(
        map(
          cryptos => {
            const currencies = [];
            let index = 0;
            return Object.keys(cryptos).map((cryptoName, index) => {
              return {
                name: cryptoName,
                price: cryptos[cryptoName].USD,
                ratingInfo: { ...ratings[index] }
              }
            });
          }
        )
      )
  }
  ...
}
```

Doing this will result in the `getProducts()` method returning an `Array` of Objects that you can simply loop through in your view.

In your CryptosComponent Template, you can then do this:

```
<h2 class="header">Crypto Price Compare</h2>
  <div *ngIf="cryptos">
  <div id="crypto-container" *ngFor="let crypto of cryptos">
    <span class="left">{{ crypto.name }}</span> - 
    <span class="right">{{ crypto.price | currency:'USD' }}</span>
    <br />
    <rating
      [ratingValue]="crypto.ratingInfo.rating"
      [numOfReviews]="crypto.ratingInfo.numOfReviews">
    </rating>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**

1. I've changed the name of `rating-value` to `ratingValue`.
2. This example uses Angular 7 where any operator that needs to be applied to an Observable needs to be `pipe`d through the `pipe` operator. If you're using Angular 4 or 5, you'll need to do it the same way you're doing as of now, by chaining `.map` to the Observable value.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cryptos-eg) for your ref.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late response. Thank you for such a detailed answer. Unfrtunately, I'm getting `Can't bind to 'ratingValue' since it isn't a known property of 'rating'.` error. And I don't understand what you mean by `ratingInfo: { ...ratings[index] }` what are those `...`? If I delete it my IDE shows me syntax error

Comment: Ups, my bad, I had the typo in my code, changed from `ratingValue` to `rating-value`. Thank you for example code!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but this doesn't make sense.

```
result[value]['ratingInfo'] = ratings[i].rating;
result[value]['ratingInfo'] = ratings[i].numOfReviews;
```

You are setting ratingInfo and immediately overwriting it with something else.  Assuming ratingInfo is an object, you probably want something like this:

```
result[value]['ratingInfo']['rating'] = ratings[i].rating;
result[value]['ratingInfo']['numOfReviews'] = ratings[i].numOfReviews;
```

Or more simply:

```
result[value]['ratingInfo'] = ratings[i]
```

Comment: None of your options works. If, I was overwriting it, then how come the commented out part was working and not overwriting? I updated my question with crypto component code to make more sense

Comment: It was all working well the way it was. I just need to figure out how to loop through more options of ratings and not just assign one and the only ratings info for each API call value (Commented out part)

Comment: Now I understood what you meant. Yeah, I changed it to not to overwrite. I even used hardcoded numbers to assign value, instead of looping through array, but I'm still getting `core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'rating' of undefined`

Comment: That error is exactly what it sounds like.  Look at like 1673 in core.js.  You will need to figure out why you are calling .rating on something that is undefined.

Comment: I don't get how `['ratingInfo']` is not undefined when assigning one hardcoded value of object literal, but is undefined when assigning `rating` value from array on iteration.